# Explanation of a Hough accumulator that does not match image

Tags: octave, hough-transform

I was having fun with image processing and hough transforms on Octave but the results are not the expected ones.
Here is my edges image: [image: I am expecting local maxima for angles with values around 0/180deg and 90/270deg]
and here is my hough accumulator (x-axis is angle in deg, y-axis is radius): [image: The local maxima are around 100deg and 270deg]
I feel like I am missing the horizontal streaks but there is no local maximum in the accumulator for the 0/180 angle values.

Also, for the vertical streaks, the value of the radius should be equal to the x value of the edge's image, but instead the values of r are very high:

exp: the first vertical line on the left of the image has an equation of x=20(approx) -> r.r = x.x + y.y -> r=x -> r=20

The overall resulting lines detected do not match the edges at all:

- Acculmulator with detected maxima:[image: Maximas are stisfyingly detected]
- Resulting lines:[image: radius values are too high and theta values are missing]

As you can see the maximas of the accumulator are satisfyingly detected but the resulting lines' radius values are too high and theta values are missing.

It almost looks like the hough transform accumulator does not correspond to the image...

Can someone help me figure out why and how to correct it?
Here is my code:

```
function [r, theta] = findScratches (img, edge)

hough = houghtf(edge,"line", pi*[0:360]/180);
threshHough = hough>.5*max(hough(:));

[r, theta] = find(threshHough>0);

%deg to rad for the trig functions
theta = theta/180*pi; 
%according to octave doc r range is 2*diagonal 
%-> bring it down to 1*diagonal or all lines are out of the picture
r = r/2;

%coefficients of the line y=ax+b
a = -cos(theta)./sin(theta);
b = r./sin(theta);

x = 1:size(img,2);
y = a * x + b;


figure(1)
imagesc(edge);
colormap gray;
hold on;
for i=1:size(y,1)
axis ij;
plot(y(i,:),x,'r','linewidth',1);
end
hold off;

endfunction
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're definitely on the right track.  Blurring the accumulator image would help before looking for the hotspots. Also, why not do a quick erode and dilate before doing the hough transform?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have definitely added some preprocessing and it helped a lot. Thank you. I remember that I still had some issues interpreting my results but it is something I want to come back to.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue - detected lines had the correct slope but were shifted. The problem is that the `r` returned by the `find(threshHough>0)` function call is in the interval of `[0,2*diag]` while the Hough transform operates with values of `r` from the interval of `[-diag,diag]`. Therefore if you change the line

`r=r/2`

to

`r=r-size(hough,1)/2`

you will get the correct offset.

Comment: This is almost correct. It should be `(size(hough,1)-1)/2`. See here for an explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48221182/7328782.

Answer (score 0):

Lets define a vector of angles (in radians):
angles=pi*[0:360]/180

You should not take this operation: theta = theta/180*pi.

Replace it by: theta = angles(theta), where theta are indices

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didn't really improve the answer. Also, I don't understand why this would change anything. If theta given by the accumulator, is in bins and not degrees, and if there are 360 bins, then each theta index is equivalent to 1 degree, therefore using theta as an index or convert it directly should be the same no?

Answer (score 0):

Some one commented above suggesting adjusting r to -diag to +diag range by

r=r-size(hough,1)/2

This worked well for me. However another difference was that I used the default angle to compute Hough Transform with angles -90 to +90. The theta range in the vector is +1 to +181. So It needs to be adjusted by -91, then convert to radian.

theta = (theta-91)*pi/180;

With above 2 changes, rest of the code works ok.

Comment: Thank you, I will be sure to test that as well.