# GNU Octave: Hough Transform

Tags: octave, hough-transform

I am attempting to use a hough transform, unfortunately it doesn't seem to be outputting r and theta that correspond with the lines Drawn. I've been trying to find the answer on this site and others but everything I've tried so far has failed.

```
I=zeros(80, 80);
for n=1:25;
  I(n+20, n+2)=1;
  I(n+1, n*2+17)=1;
  I(n+1, n*2+16)=1;
  end

hough = houghtf(I,"line", pi*[0:360]/180);
threshHough = hough>.9*max(hough(:));
[r, theta] = find(threshHough>0)
%theta = (theta-91)*pi/180
%r=r-size(hough,1)/2

imshow(I)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `houghtf` function in Octave parameterizes a line as

```
r = x*cos(theta) + y*sin(theta)
```

The output is an NxM matrix where the first dimension represents `r` and the second one `theta`.

The [documentation](https://octave.sourceforge.io/image/function/houghtf.html) is not very clear on the `r` parameter. All it says is that `N = 2*diag_length - 1`, with `diag_length` the diagonal length of the image. But it doesn't even tell you where the origin is. After some experimentation, I found that the origin is at `(N-1)/2`. Thus, after finding a peak at indices (`ii`,`jj`),

```
r = ii - (size(hough,1)-1)/2;
```

The `theta` parameter is described much better in the documentation: the bin returned corresponds to the values given in the input. So `theta` is the index into the array `pi*[0:360]/180` that you pass to `houghft`. You can write:

```
angles = pi*[0:360]/180;
theta = angles(jj);
```

Do note that the Hough transform deals with the orientation of the line, not the direction of the line. You can parameterize the same line using `theta` or `theta+180`. Thus, the `hough` image produced by the code above is redundant, with all orientations repeated twice (actually, the result for orientation 0 degrees is repeated twice, at 180 and 360 degrees). Instead, use

```
angles = pi*[0:179]/180;
```

Next, simply thresholding the Hough transform and getting all pixels is not the best approach: some peaks will be much stronger, leading to bow-tie--shaped detections, of which you'll want to use only the highest point. The `'shrink'` method of the `bwmorph` function is a quick-and-dirty way of reducing the detections after the threshold to a single point, but it's not guaranteed to be on the highest point. Note also that for lines at 0 degrees, the bow-tie is cut in half at the edge of the image, with the other half appearing back at angle 179 degrees. This requires extra effort to fix. Below, I fixed it by extending `angles` a bit, and then removing duplicate points.

Finally, when parameterizing the line, it seems that Octave picks `x` as the fist index and `y` as the second index into the image, which is opposite of what `imshow` does.

Putting it all together, we get:

```
% Create test image with some lines
I = zeros(80, 80);
for n=1:25;
  I(n+20,n+2) = 1;
  I(n+1,n*2+17) = 1;
  I(n+1,n*2+16) = 1;
end
I(34:73,55) = 1;
I(60,15:64) = 1;

% Compute the Hough transform
angles = pi*[-10:189]/180;
hough = houghtf(I,"line",angles);

% Detect maxima in the Hough transform -- this is a bit of a hack
detect = hough>.5*max(hough(:));
detect = bwmorph(detect,'shrink',inf);
[ii, jj] = find(detect);
r = ii - (size(hough,1)-1)/2;
theta = angles(jj);

% Remove duplicate points by deleting any point with an angle 
% outside of the interval [0,180).
dup = theta<-1e-6 | theta>=pi-1e-6;
r(dup) = [];
theta(dup) = [];

% Compute line parameters (using Octave's implicit singleton expansion)
r = r(:)';
theta = theta(:)';
x = repmat([1;80],1,length(r)); % 2xN matrix, N==length(r)
y = (r - x.*cos(theta))./sin(theta); % solve line equation for y
% The above goes wrong when theta==0, fix that:
horizontal = theta < 1e-6;
x(:,horizontal) = r(horizontal);
y(:,horizontal) = [1;80];

% Plot
figure
imshow(I)
hold on
plot(y,x,'r-','linewidth',2) % note the reversed x and y!
```

[image]

The diagonal lines are off by one pixel because the way we detected them. We never looked for the location of the local maximum, we took all pixels above a threshold and picked the point in the middle of that.

Comment: Thank you very much for giving such a detailed answer. I am still confused I guess about two things: The resulting r and theta values that I receive are r= 120, and 106, and theta =2.6704, and 5,8119. I plotted the first line using the trig equation and I got a line that isn't even close to either of the two lines in my initial image. Secondly, and I'm sure this is a stupid question, Why do I see 4 hot spots in the hough image?

Comment: @mcally: don't forget that you should index `I(y,x)` into your image. MATLAB and Octave index the matrix row in the first index, but they typically call `x` the horizontal axis (2nd index). Weird, I know! I don't know why you see 4 spots in your Hough transform, I don't know what your image is like. But if `find` returns two values for each index, there are only 2 pixels above your threshold.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I'm still having an issue with the resulting r and theta for some reason. For the single vertical line output by the code below, I receive theta equaling pi/2 and 3pi/2. when it should be 0 Correct?imshow(I)
I=zeros(80, 80);
I(:, 20)=1;
angles = pi*[0:360]/180;
hough = houghtf(I,"line", angles);
threshHough = hough>.9*max(hough(:));
[ii, jj] = find(threshHough>0);
r = ii-1
theta = angles(jj)

Comment: Again, the second index is x, but x is still horizontal... totally confusing, I know! In any case, a vertical line has an angle of pi/2. It also has an angle of 3pi/2 because you can go up or down on that same line. The line has an orientation, but no direction. If you display your `hough` image, you'll see the two halves are identical. You should only compute half of it! Set `angles = pi*[0:179]/180` to prevent duplicate orientations.

Comment: Okay now its making a lot more sense. I do have one more problem that I didn't notice until now though, the vertical line output has an x intercept of 132 instead of 20 (using the code I included before). I've tried several other values for the line's x intercept, but I haven't been able to figure out what is happening. Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: @mcally: You are right. I didn't think about the `r` parameter needing positive and negative values. I experimented a bit and found the correct equation for `r`. See updated answer.

Comment: You've been so helpful and I'm sorry to bother you with yet another problem. But the code as amended by your latest line works only when the line is completely vertical or horizontal. I've been trying to identify on my own why it breaks down with angled lines unsuccessfully, but I'm afraid I'm not familiar enough with Octave. The issue perplexes me even further by producing seemingly random lines which have little resemblance to those of the original image, x and y intercepts are often completely different, and sometimes the slope is negative when it should be positive.

Comment: @mcally: I think I found the problem: the x and y axes seem inverted. I've amended the answer to also draw lines on the image, so you see how it's presumably supposed to be done. I'm surprised at the poor documentation and the inconsistency with the `hough` function.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yeah I'm pretty surprised as well, I wish I could just read up on this stuff, but the documentation on this is a tiny paragraph or two. I love Octave because it's free, but Matlab was better about this. Thanks again for being patient with me on this.

Comment: MATLAB is better about documentation, but it doesn't have a `houghtf` function. :)

Comment: Hey something minor, but what needs to change when the resolution of the initial image increases?

Comment: Where I wrote `[1;80]` in the section on drawing lines, I was being lazy. 80 is the size of the image, vertical size in one and horizontal size in the other.

Comment: That's what I thought, but when I put in the right values the result kind of broke down. Maybe my initial image is too complex. Does that happen with hough transforms? I can kinda see with the 80x80 test that the detected lines aren't just offset but also skewed a little as if the mass of another line attracts it. Might have something to do bwmorph shrink, or it could be something more.

Comment: @mcally No, that's just purely not finding the actual peak in the Hough transform, the estimated parameters being a bit off. But if your image gets much more complex, finding the peaks properly gets increasingly complex also, and if they're close together they will influence each other.

Comment: Hey, back to the party. I have a somewhat related question. If I run a hough transform on a set of parallel lines (a barcode) and set the houghthresh low enough to pick up up most of the bars, it also outputs lines that go corner to opposite corner. Is that just the nature of the houghtf? or is there a way to avoid it. I mean I think I get where it's coming from. corner to opposite corner crosses a lot of white pixels, but it also crosses a lot of black ones as well, pretty much 50/50. Does that not even matter?

Comment: The height of the peak is equal to the number of white pixels. You can find the orientation that gives the most peaks, and ignore the peaks at other orientations.

Comment: So you're saying look for the mode of theta, and then find mode +/- x radians?

Comment: @mcally: Yes, project the transform onto the theta axis, find the peak, then look for local maxima in the full transform near that theta location (this second part you should probably not do in the projection on the r axis).